# How does Qiskit's oracle synthesizer work?

Tags: qiskit, oracles

Qiskit provides a [phase oracle method](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.PhaseOracle.html) that takes a Boolean formula as input and returns a phase oracle circuit for that function as output.
Their [source code](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/circuit/library/phase_oracle.html#PhaseOracle) informed me that the synthesis uses the [Tweedledum's `pkrm_synth` method](https://github.com/boschmitt/tweedledum/blob/master/src/Synthesis/pkrm_synth.cpp) for the actual synthesis.

However, apart from the fact that it somehow uses some combination of things called psuedo-Kronecker expression and Reed-Muller code (hence the 'pkrm' acronym), I could not decipher how the synthesis is being performed and what kind of algorithm is being used due to the lack of C++ proficiency.

If there are any documentations for the `pkrm_synth` method or the `Tweedledum` package in general, or if anyone recognizes the algorithm being used in the method, any such help would be greatly appreciated.